# Разница между global и $GLOBALS

Tags: php

В интернете видел что пишут разница лишь в написании, так ли это?

Снизу товарищ `Saidolim` написал один пример, хочу продолжить вопрос...

**Есть такой код**

```
/// Пример 1
$str = "Simple text";
$a = function()
{
    global $str;
    $str = "edited";
};
$a();
echo $str."\n"; /// edited

/// Пример 2
$str = "Simple text";
$a = function()
{
    $GLOBALS["str"] = "edited";
};
$a();
echo $str."\n"; /// edited

/// Пример 3
$str = "Simple text";
$temp = "";
$a = function()
{
    $GLOBALS["temp"] = &$GLOBALS["str"];
};
$a();
echo "[".$str."] [".$temp."]\n"; /// [Simple text] [Simple text]

/// Пример 4
$str = "Simple text";
$temp = "";
$a = function()
{
    global $str, $temp;
    $temp = &$str;
};
$a();
echo "[".$str."] [".$temp."]\n"; /// [Simple text] []
```

Первый пример выводит как и ожидается измененное значение, второй пример то же самое...казалось бы отличия нет, идем дальше! В третьем примере в функции мы делаем жесткую ссылку для элементов суперглобального массива выводит как и ожидается одно и то же слово, и вот смотрим четвертый пример и ... я в ступоре он не линкует и выводит только переменнную `$str`, а переменную `$temp` оставляет пустой, почему?

P.S Написал тут ибо не хотел спамить вопросами по одному и тому же

Comment: Эмм .... global это конструкция языка для объявления глобальной переменной. $_GLOBALS ассоциативный массив эти переменные содержащий. ну да, позволяют добраться до одного и того же, но совершенно по разному.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Инструкция `global` обращается к глобальному массиву `$GLOBALS`. И получает значение переменной `$GLOBALS['var']`. Отличие только в написании.

P.S. Совет при использовании глобальных переменных: держитесь от них подальше, используя их только тогда, когда без них не обойтись.

**Злоупотребление глобальными переменными может довести человека анализирующего ваш код до белой горячки.**

Comment: Не бойтесь, мой вопрос несет не практический характер =)

Comment: Вы точно уверены что кроме отличия в написании больше нет?

Comment: @MaximPro абсолютно. global $var является полным эквивалентом $var = &$GLOBALS['var']

Comment: Кстати забавная конструкция с привязкой переменной, видел в доках =) Ну хорошо, я думаю никто не будет против если я отмечу ваш ответ

Comment: @MaximPro максимум можно предположить, что есть микросекундная разница в скорости этих функций, но она настолько мала, что ее даже не стоит учитывать.

Comment: гляньте, я вопрос обновил, что можете сказать по данному поводу?

Answer (score 2):

[Обратимся к документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.globals.php)(это, кстати, очень полезно делать)

> $GLOBALS — Ссылки на все переменные глобальной области видимости
>
> Это 'суперглобальная' или автоматическая глобальная переменная. Это
>   просто означает что она доступна во всех контекстах скрипта. Нет
>   необходимости выполнять global $variable; для доступа к ней внутри
>   метода или функции.

Фактически, они предоставляют доступ к одним и тем же объектам. Разница только в способе использования.

И как верно заметил @Firepro, использование `global` либо `$GLOBALS` - это **очень** плохо.

Answer (score 2):

1. `global` думаю работает быстрее. Так как подход другой. Но когда используете переменную, вам трудно понять она глобальная или нет.
2. `$GLOBALS` более читальный и легко понять. Так как очевидно выдно что переменная глобальная.
3. Если в функции хотите использовать `unset` глобального переменного, вы должны использовать `unset($GLOBALS['varname'])`, а не `global $varname; unset($varname);`.

Более детально думаю можете узнать [тут](http://blog.golemon.com/2006/05/last-month-at-phptek-i-gave.html)

---

**UPD**

для сравнения этих команд. предлогаю проверить следуюшый код:

```
function test_global() {   
  global $var1, $var2;   
  $var2 =& $var1;   
}   
function test_globals() {   
  $GLOBALS['var3'] =& $GLOBALS['var1'];   
}   
$var1 = 5;   
$var2 = 0;
$var3 = 0;   
test_global();   
print $var1 ." > ". $var2 ." ";   
echo "<br/>";
test_globals();   
print $var1 ." > ". $var3 ;
```

результат

```
5 > 0 
5 > 5
```

---

Но я бы посоветовал использовать следуюшую схему, когда работаете с переменнами:

```
function myFunc(&$myVar)
{
    $myVar = 10;
}

$foo = 0;
myFunc($foo);
var_dump($foo); // результат 10
```

Тут как видите, переменная передается функции как ссылка, и функция имеет право менять его значение. И Внутри функции легче понимать, что кто то тебе дал переменную и ты меняеш его значение.

Лучше обойти глобальности, чем использовать его.

Comment: Тут меня интересует чисто "спортивный" характер, а не практический =)

Comment: @MaximPro аа ну тогда сорри

Comment: @MaximPro когда читаете значение глобальной переменной, проблемы нету. Но когда хотите его изменить.. попробуйте код в `UPD`

Comment: А с чем связано то что не получается залинковать переменную, которая объявлена с помощью ключевого слова `global`?

Answer (score 1):

Отличие между суперглобальной переменной **$GLOBALS** и ключевым словом **global** в php на самом деле есть.

Дело в том, что **$GLOBALS** обращается к переменной непосредственно, а **global** *внедряет* переменную из глобальной области видимости (и, насколько могу судить, только из неё) в соответствующую локальную область видимости.

В документации [написано об этом, но лишь вскользь](http://php.net/language.variables.scope#language.variables.scope.references). И для Zend Engine 2 и phpng ситуация аналогична.